# How do I view the auto_increment value for a table

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

The only way I know is `show create table MyTable`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
  FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
 WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = SCHEMA()
   AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'tbl_name';
```

Answer (score 10):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "tablename";
```

the `auto_increment` column will show the count.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`LAST_INSERTED_ID`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.

Comment: There is no `LAST_INSERTED_ID` function, `LAST_INSERT_ID` is connection specific not table specific. This answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, but I don't have RENDER_ERROR in my case.
Here is a copy of the TV log, with BUFFERING_START and TV reboot before BUFFERING_COMPLETE

2018/08/01 10:23:54.934 - #67 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] Full transport data: {"transport_type":"http_file","mimetype":"video/mp2t","address":"http://contents.teveo.local:81/Movies_1806_PacificRimUprising_mv_multi_PAL_scas_enc.m2te","session":269708,"duration":6394,"resumeTimeCode":176,"drm":"lynk","drmServer":"10.11.0.254","token":"198","audioTracks":[{"pid":785,"language":"en"},{"pid":787,"language":"fr"},{"pid":788,"language":"it"},{"pid":786,"language":"es"},{"pid":789,"language":"ru"},{"pid":784,"language":"de"}],"contentFileId":1395}
2018/08/01 10:23:54.946 - #68 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] Preferred AUDIO languages: [fr]
2018/08/01 10:23:54.948 - #69 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] VOD stream is declared as encrypted
2018/08/01 10:23:54.950 - #70 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] [decoder LOCK] <<< released by [init]
2018/08/01 10:23:54.960 - #71 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] _dispatchEvent(init)
2018/08/01 10:23:54.963 - #72 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] [decoder LOCK] >>> acquired by [start]
2018/08/01 10:23:54.969 - #73 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] _START
2018/08/01 10:23:54.978 - #74 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] _KILL(play_requested=false)
2018/08/01 10:23:54.994 - #75 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] Selecting the MEDIA source
2018/08/01 10:23:55.004 - #76 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] EventWatcher: Waiting for one of event(s) ["SOURCE_CONNECTED"]...
2018/08/01 10:23:55.010 - #77 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] _dispatchEvent(wait)
2018/08/01 10:23:55.720 - #78 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] Event received from TV plugin: 126 | {param1:0,parm2:48,parm3:43,param2:48,param3:43}
2018/08/01 10:23:55.721 - #79 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] Device source [43] is ready
2018/08/01 10:23:55.723 - #80 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] EventWatcher: [SOURCE_CONNECTED] event received => the pending request SUCCEEDED
2018/08/01 10:23:55.726 - #81 - DBG - {TerminalInterfaceSamsungPluginGenericHandler} Event received from SEF_TV plugin: 0 | 126 | {param1:0,parm2:48,parm3:43,param2:48,param3:43}
2018/08/01 10:23:55.730 - #82 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] Initializing Lynk DRM with server 10.11.0.254
2018/08/01 10:23:56.475 - #83 - INF - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] Start decoder playback for VOD content: http://contents.teveo.local:81/Movies_1806_PacificRimUprising_mv_multi_PAL_scas_enc.m2te?token=198|COMPONENT=LYNK|TYPE=2
2018/08/01 10:23:56.691 - #84 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] EventWatcher: Waiting for one of event(s) ["RENDERING_START"]...
2018/08/01 10:24:01.547 - #85 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] Event received from Player plugin: STREAM_INFO_READY
2018/08/01 10:24:01.583 - #86 - DBG - [samsung_vod_player] [269708] Event received from Player plugin: BUFFERING_START
2018/08/01 10:30:02.867 - DBG - logger - ---------- PAGE CONTEXT [mw_online|#62] ----------
2018/08/01 10:29:48.827 - #1 - DBG - {TTerminalInterfaceSamsung.GetLocalData} Key { device_ref_timestamp } not found in local data
2018/08/01 10:29:48.934 - #2 - DBG - {TTerminalInterfaceSamsung.InitPlugin} Plugin 'time' successfully initialized
2018/08/01 10:29:48.941 - #3 - DBG - {TTerminalInterfaceSamsung.GetLocalData} Value { platform_clock_timestamp_fix => 3600000 } retrieved from LOCAL_STORAGE
2018/08/01 10:29:48.946 - #4 - DBG - {TTerminalInterfaceSamsung.GetLocalData} Value { timezone_offset_to_gmt => 120 } retrieved from LOCAL_STORAGE
2018/08/01 10:29:48.948 - #5 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.GetTimezoneOffsetFix} Timezone offset fix updated to: 0 min
2018/08/01 10:29:48.957 - #6 - DBG - {TTerminalInterfaceSamsung.GetLocalData} Value { timestamp_fix => 116 } retrieved from LOCAL_STORAGE
2018/08/01 10:29:49.069 - #7 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.Init2} First time update will occur in 1969 sec
2018/08/01 10:29:49.082 - #8 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.InitAjaxClient} Ajax client 'update_time' successfully initialized
2018/08/01 10:29:49.086 - #9 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.InitAjaxClient} Ajax client 'check_server' successfully initialized
2018/08/01 10:29:49.088 - #10 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.StartTimer} Starting timer 'first_time_update' [1968.688 sec]
2018/08/01 10:29:49.090 - #11 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.StartTimer} Starting timer 'check_server' [30 sec]
2018/08/01 10:29:49.096 - #12 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.RegisterEventCallback} Callback registered for DOM event [unload]: function TerminalInterfaceUnloadEventCallback()
2018/08/01 10:29:49.101 - #13 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.RegisterEventCallback} Callback registered for DOM event [beforeunload]: function TerminalInterfaceBeforeUnloadEventCallback()
2018/08/01 10:29:49.106 - #14 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.RegisterEventCallback} Callback registered for DOM event [load]: function TerminalInterfaceLoadEventCallback()
2018/08/01 10:29:49.110 - #15 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.RegisterEventCallback} Callback registered for DOM event [error]: function TerminalInterfaceErrorEventCallback(e)
2018/08/01 10:29:49.112 - #16 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.RegisterEventCallback} Callback registered for DOM event [message]: function TerminalInterfaceWindowMessageEventCallback(e)
2018/08/01 10:29:49.115 - #17 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.RegisterEventCallback} Callback registered for DOM event [unhandledrejection]: function (e) {e.preventDefault(),g_terminal.LogDebug("{TTerminalInterface} Unhandled Promise rejecti...
2018/08/01 10:29:49.120 - #18 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.RegisterEventCallback} Callback registered for DOM event [load]: function () {setTimeout('window.nav = spatial_nav = new SpatialNav(spatial_nav_config); $(window).tr...
2018/08/01 10:29:49.123 - #19 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.Init2} >>>>>> TerminalInterface initialized [#62|http://des-service-node.eona-des.fr/terminal/state/startup/boot]
2018/08/01 10:29:49.130 - #20 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.RegisterEventCallback} Callback registered for DOM event [load]: function TerminalInterfaceSamsungLoadHandler()
2018/08/01 10:29:49.133 - #21 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.ExecuteCallback} Calling callback... [Global instance 'init' / Callback #0]
2018/08/01 10:29:49.134 - #22 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.RegisterEventCallback} Callback registered for DOM event [message]: function keyManagementWindowMessageEventCallback(e)
2018/08/01 10:29:49.135 - #23 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.ExecuteCallback} Callback executed with result = undefined
2018/08/01 10:29:49.135 - #24 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.ExecuteCallback} Calling callback... [Global instance 'init' / Callback #1]
2018/08/01 10:29:49.138 - #25 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.RegisterEventCallback} Callback registered for DOM event [keydown]: function _vkey_keydown_handler(e)
2018/08/01 10:29:49.139 - #26 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.RegisterEventCallback} Callback registered for DOM event [load]: function _vkey_load_handler()
2018/08/01 10:29:49.140 - #27 - DBG - {TTerminalInterface.ExecuteCallback} Callback executed with result = undefined
2018/08/01 10:29:49.170 - #28 - INF - ---------------------------- Terminal 10.11.1.11 started.

Comment: Please try formatting your post. This is not very readable. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help